# nodejs - session lost while switching from www to non-www

Tags: node.js, session, express, nginx

(New to web development)

I'm using `nginx` for my `nodejs` website on a `Digital Ocean` instance.

I'm using `passport.js`for facebook login on [http://www.example.org/login](http://example.org/login). My callback URL is [http://www.example.org/auth/facebook/callback](http://example.org/auth/facebook/callback).

The session works if I access the website using `http://www....` but it gets lost if I switch from http://www to http://

I've already tried creating a redirect in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` using:

```
server_name example.org
rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.example.org/$1 permanent;
```

but this isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

Can anybody help me with setting the session for both `www` and `non-www` versions of my domain in `nodejs`, or correctly writing the redirect?

Comment: Cuz www and the non-www is a different set of domains, but what you can do it to set the cookie into a subdomain compatible one. Something like `.example.com` instead of `example.com`

Comment: Hey thanks for that, I ended up fixing the redirect bug within nginx so that handled the problem, thanks!